# Can I get custom address autocomplete options using Facebook Marketing API Targeting Search?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am building a `targeting_spec` for an ad set, and in the `geo_locations` object, I want to set the `custom_locations` to the address of a business or a city or whatever information I have available. I can do this easily using Ads Manager in the Locations search box. I simply start typing the address, and Facebook shows me if they know about the address/city or not.

I've already noticed I can specify a custom location manually like this:

```
geo_locations: {
    custom_locations: [{ address_string: '900 Washington Avenue, Racine, WI', radius: 25 }]
}
```

And that address will appear as the selected address in the "Locations" section of the ad set's audience in Ads Manager.

But there are lots of times where Facebook has a different address on their end than what I find on my client's website. I see this when I type in the address while building an ad set in Ads Manager:

[image]

Sometimes, Facebook will list the address in a different city or something. What I'd like to do is be able to use the Targeting Search API to search for an address and be able to view and choose an option from the results.

I visited the [Targeting Search](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search) documentation, but there is no mention of searching for an address - only country, city, ZIP, etc.

I also used Developer Tools to inspect the AJAX calls going out when I type in an address while editing the ad set, and I see that it's calling `/search` with parameters `type=adgeolocation` and `qs=%5B%22900%20Washington%20Avenue%2C%20Racine%2C%20WI%22%5D`. But if I go to Graph API Explorer and copy the exact same parameters, I always get a response like:

```
"data": [
    {
      "key": "900 Washington Avenue, Racine, WI",
      "category": "no_match"
    }
  ]
```

I have searched Google, searched Facebook's documentation, searched here, and I can find no mention of searching for an address to make sure Facebook has reference to it or has it under a different city or something.

Should I just always pass the `address_string` as my client has it on their site and just hope that Facebook knows about the address and is able to determine where it is? Or is there actually a way to do an address search using `/search`?

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: @sGambolati I asked this question on the Facebook Marketing Developers Q/A group (https://www.facebook.com/groups/336274920162559/permalink/656163188173729/), and one user responded that he didn't think they allowed this, which appears to be the case, since I never found a way to do it. We ended up just having to pass the address we have to Facebook and hope they accept it. FYI, the call to create an ad with that address would blow up if they couldn't find the address.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `&place_fallback=true` to the request (found this using the dev tools).

Another quirk that I found was that if I ran the request with my "System User", I got different responses than through the UI. I was able to get around this by using the access_token I found in the dev tools when using through the UI. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked!

Comment: I'm not sure what that request is returning, but it doesn't appear to be address information specific to the address I'm passing in via the "qs" param. I see results being returned, but it's seemingly random locations all around the address I passed in. Do you have any context to what they're returning?